# How to fix "Ad failed to load : 3" error in Libgdx

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

I am trying to add Admob in Libgdx but when I run it on my phone I always get an error "Ad failed to load : 3" as last line in logcat.

I have provided payment information at Admob, and they have verified them.
I have tried to add Admob to pure Android app, without Libgdx, and it shows an add (banner), but when it comes to Libgdx it doesn't work.

Here is my AndroidLauncher:

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {

private static final String adUnitId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
private AdView adView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    View gameView = initializeForView(new MyGdxGame(), config);
    setupAds();

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams =
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
            .build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    layout.addView(adView, adParams);
    layout.addView(gameView);

    setContentView(layout);
}

private void setupAds() {
    adView = new AdView(this);

    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            System.out.println("Banner loaded!");
        }
    });

    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(adUnitId);
}
```

Here are last lines of logcat:

W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mp4v-esdp

I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es

I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3

Here is AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:appCategory="game"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:isGame="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/GdxTheme">

    <activity
        android:name="com.test.game.AndroidLauncher"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

</application>
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error Code 3 : ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL**

**Description**  : The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.

Why is  it Happening : Advertisers can target specific regions, platforms and user profiles based on business relevance, which can sometimes result in lower availability of Ads for a particular region or user profile. Error code suggests that the implementation is correct, and that the Ad Request was not filled because of lack of availability of a suitable Ad at that particular instant of time when an Ad Request was sent from the app.

Policy related restrictions on certain Apps or Ad Units will also lead to Error Code 3 being returned in response to Ad Requests.

**What Can The Pub Do About it :**

→ As we cannot manipulate advertiser demand, there are no particular ‘fixes’ for this error - the pub can cross-check the Ad Unit implementation to ensure that the Ad Units are implemented correctly.

→ Mediation : In some instances, certain Ad Networks may have limited performance in some regions or for specific formats, in which case the pubs can try using mediation to add other Ad Networks that may potentially perform well.

→ Check for Policy status for the Pub ID, the App and the Ad Unit ID. Also check the Brand Safety flags and Coppa status.

→ If the Pub can obtain Test Ads for an Ad Unit (Instructions) - then their implementation is correct, and the Ad Units will serve Ads normally when an Ad is available depending on advertiser demand.

Comment: So when app is published to app store ads will appear to users, but I just can't see them now?

Comment: have you applied filter (ad category) ?

Comment: I have not applied anything.

Answer (score 1):

Error code 3 of AdView means there are no ads to fill right now, you can see that your code is working on debug mode, but sometimes depending on your location you might not be able to served with ads.

You can use Mediation, or increase number of Ad providers from console to overcome this issue.